# Picking Thermistor for Low Power Push-Pull Output Amplifier

Tags: audio, temperature, thermistor

Regarding the following low power push pull transistor "Deacy" amplifier:

[image: Deacy low power push pull amp]

what type and value of thermistor might be used as depicted in this graphic:

[image]

to add temperature compensation to this circuit?

The thermistor graphic is from a manufacturer's page about [NTC Thermistors](http://www.amwei.com/views.asp?hw_id=63). Presumably the 39R would be repaced with a resistor and thermistor that have a parallel resistance of 39R at normal operating temperature. I just don't know how to select appropriate values without just buying 3-5 values and testing them one-by-one.

Comment: Yucc.  The positive supply at the bottom and negative at the top make your schematics confusing to look at.  And what the heck is R8 with that line thru it like that?

Comment: Euuuugh! What a nasty circuit! Just use a Vbe divider... and that completely unnecessary audio transformer...

Answer (score 2):

The compensation needs to match the change in the forward drop of the base-emitter junction of a germanium transistor. For a Ge diode this NTC is linear at 2.5 mV/°C. So you'll need to choose a combination of fixed resistance and an NTC thermistor to give this value when they are connected in parallel to give your 39R.

Comment: Someone suggested using a Ge diode or transistor in diode configuration but they then deleted their comment. That seemed like a great idea to me. With the transistors all connected closely to a chunk of aluminum and with same Re and maybe a small base resistor to match the DCR of the transformer, all 3 transistors should track perfectly no?

Comment: @ioplex   Well the voltage at that point comes out at -0.157V so it sounds feasible.

Comment: Actually I just tried it and it sounds really bad. I found a Ge PNP that gave me 9.5 mA through the transformer just like the resistor and on the scope it looked ok. But the sound was awful. This circuit is very touchy.